# Can i pass a list as a parameter to a method in Scala/Java which is defined this way detectFormatAutomatically(delimitersForDetection:Char*)

Tags: java, scala

I'm creating a library to help correct CSV, in order to do it, I'm using univocity parser library.
 I'm using the CSVParserSettings class method `detectFormatAutomatically` which is defined this way 
`detectFormatAutomatically(delimitersForDetection:Char*)`
Is there any way I can pass a scala list or any list as an argument in order to not having to define this chars in the code itself.
I should be able to pass a string with the chars via Linux terminal and then parse it to a list of chars in my Scala code. The problem is that I get the list of chars but I cannot pass it as an argument to the method.
My code:

```
val settings = new CsvParserSettings()

val list = List(',',';',':','|')

settings.detectFormatAutomatically(list)
```

The error is: Type mismatch, expected: Char, actual: List[Char]

Is there any way I can get what I want to do.

Comment: `settings.detectFormatAutomatically(list:_*)` should work.

Comment: @vindev You should make that an answer not a comment.

Comment: @Tim      done. Made it community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
settings.detectFormatAutomatically(list:_*)
```